# How to upload file to amazon s3 using gin framework

Tags: go, amazon-s3, file-upload, go-gin

I am trying to upload a file to Amazon S3 Using gin framework of Go. Since aws-sdc requires to read the file i need to open file using os.open('filename').But since i am getting the file from "formFile" I don't have the path of the file to open, so `os.Open()` is giving error

> The system cannot find the file specified.

My approach is as follows

```
package controllers

import (
    "bytes"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/credentials"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
)

const (
    S3_REGION = "MY REGION"
    S3_BUCKET = "<MY BUCKET>"
)

func UploadDocument(c *gin.Context) {
    var Buf bytes.Buffer
    file, _ := c.FormFile("file")

    creds := credentials.NewSharedCredentials("", "default")

    s, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region:      aws.String(S3_REGION),
        Credentials: creds,
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    err = AddFilesToS3(s, file.fileName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func AddFilesToS3(s *session.Session, fileDir string) error {
    file, err := os.Open(fileDir)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    fileInfo, _ := file.Stat()
    var size int64 = fileInfo.Size()
    buffer := make([]byte, size)
    file.Read(buffer)

    _, err = s3.New(s).PutObject(&s3.PutObjectInput{
        Bucket:               aws.String(S3_BUCKET),
        Key:                  aws.String("myfolder" + "/" + fileDir),
        ACL:                  aws.String("private"),
        Body:                 bytes.NewReader(buffer),
        ContentLength:        aws.Int64(size),
        ContentType:          aws.String(http.DetectContentType(buffer)),
        ContentDisposition:   aws.String("attachment"),
        ServerSideEncryption: aws.String("AES256"),
    })
    return err

}
```

I am sending my file through POSTMAN like this

[image]

what I need to pass to my 'AddFilesToS3' function, since I am sending just the file name, `os.Open(fileDir)` is failing to look to the actual path of the file.
Where am I doing wrong or is there any better method available to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not even reading the file from the form.

You need to call [FileHeader.Open](https://godoc.org/mime/multipart#FileHeader). This returns a [multipart.File](https://godoc.org/mime/multipart#File) which implements the standard `io.Reader` interface.

You should change `AddFilesToS3` to take a filename and `io.Reader`. This can then be called for files from gin as well as regular files.

```
  fileHeader, err := c.FormFile("file")
  // check err
  f, err := fileHeader.Open()
  // check err
  err = AddFilesToS3(s, fileHeader.fileName, f)
```

And your `AddFilesToS3` is now:

```
func AddFilesToS3(s *session.Session, fileDir string, r io.Reader) error {
  // left as an exercise for the OP
```

You may need to pass `fileHeader.Size()` as well.